# Waveform for one byte sent over 3.3 V TTL

Tags: oscilloscope, waveform

I have this question in my lab which I am not able to solve. It would be really appreciated if I could get some help with this.

The question is: I need to draw the waveform for 1 byte sent over 3.3 V TTL.

I have seen the waveform for this on the RS-232. I was wondering if someone could tell me how the 3.3 V TTL one will differ from the RS232 one.

This is the exact question I have:

> You will be using an oscilloscope to investigate serial port of the Raspberry Pi. One standard for serial communications is RS-232, but the port we will use is 3.3V TTL.
>
> 12. Draw the waveform you would expect for one byte sent over this serial link.

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/215

Comment: If you have the time to go down the rabbit hole, you can study the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART

Answer (score 1):

> "You will be using an oscilloscope to investigate the serial port of a Raspberry Pi. One standard for serial communications is RS-232, but the port we will use is 3.3V TTL. Draw the waveform you would expect for one byte sent over this serial link."

So this question is a multi-faceted gem, designed to make students dig into the details of RS-232, TTL, and protocols.  Since it is a coursework question, this "answer" will be Socratic in nature.

- What is RS-232? That is an old standard for the electrical parameters for serial communication. Typically this is the wiring, voltages, and "DB" or "D-Sub" connectors used such as DB-9 or DB-25. RS-232 is a specification and states that signalling happens with certain voltage ranges above and beyond 0 volts, such as +/-12v. It is an old standard, so uses larger voltages than we typically use today. It has stuck around however, because it is very robust and long cable lengths are possible.
- What is TTL? TTL means "transistor-transistor logic" and implies digital signals sent between digital chips. So this voltage range is 0-5v for logic low and high. This standard was, for a long time, exclusively 5 volts. Until CMOS came around, with it's capability to do 15v or even 20v. However, with more modern digital chips, this has reduced greatly to 3.3v, 2.5v, or even 1.8v in an effort to save power and increase speed.

Ok so one major difference is that an RS-232 signal will range from +12v to -12v, whereas a TTL signal will range from 0v to +3.3v.

And of course a byte of data is eight bits.

Then you must consider *what* digital information is being sent; or in other words, the protocol. And at what speed, or baud rate. In a single-wire configuration, provision must be made to indicate when a transmission is starting, so that the receiver knows to "listen." This is called a *start-bit*. And there may need to be one or more *stop bits*, with the bits of the actual data in the middle.

So your waveform would look like (0-3.3v):
* Start bit
* Eight bits of data
* Stop bit(s)

Additional research terms: RS-232, TTL, Serial, Protocol, baud rate, start/stop bit, parity.

Comment: Just as a point of information, as I recall the RS-232 spec defines a mark as a voltage of -3V or lower and a space as a voltage of +3V or greater. Some conforming RS-232 signals are just +/-5V. The +/-12V signals were common when computing equipment commonly had +/-12V power supplies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is really a fair question for the student, but it certainly can be answered by searching. TTL is short-form in this case for a signal that would generate the correct waveform if passed through a driver chip such as a [MAX232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max232.pdf). It generally means Transistor-Transistor Logic, implying logic levels of < 0.4 or > 2.7V, but up to 5V or a bit more is acceptable. 5V on a Raspberry Pi  input is not acceptable and will likely destroy the MCU.

In the world of RS-232 asynchronous communications, it's come to mean the **logic signal** that drives the driver, whether that's CMOS levels or TTL levels. For example [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/449) driver circuit description refers to "5V TTL" and "2.8V CMOS TTL". Especially the latter gives me a twitch, but I know exactly what they mean.

If you look at the driver datasheets linked above, you should be able to predict what waveform output of the Raspberry Pi would generate the desired RS-232 waveform. Also keep in mind the logic levels used in the Raspberry Pi (hint: not 0V/5V).

Answer (score -1):

TTL only implies logic levels, not protocol.

Same with RS-232 but has higher v for more noise immunity. These voltages can be as high as +/-25V but tend to be around +/-12V. Note that they are bipolar.

Answer (score -2):

TTL is Transistor-Transistor-Logic, that is a specification for ICs and they are many lines parallel. So if you may have 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 bit going in parallel or multiplexed. I don't think you can say "waveform for 1 byte sent over 3.3V TTL" because "TTL" isn't a data transfer specification. Now if you use a shift register, parallel-in-serial out or serial-in-parallel-out, or bi-directional, you will just have the 3.3V (in this case, usually it would be 5V) high signal coming out of the serial output pin on a high bit and 0V on a low bit, coming out each time the clock pin goes from low to high. So the "wave-form" could be a constant 3.3V line the whole entire time if your byte is 0xFF, 256, 0b11111111, or 0V the entire time if your value is 0. I wouldn't speak about "TTL waveform". But I guess some people might use this jargon to speak about RS-232 signals which follow the RS-232 standard in all but the voltage level, +5V/0V instead of +12V/-12V.

Now, RS232 has various options, some use more and some use less wires. Synchronous and asynchronous mode. Synchronous uses a clock signal on pin 15, 17. But usually RS232 is known as the "asynchronous interface" because you only hook up TX, RX, and GND pins. In this case the data rate setting is relevant. 100, 200, 400, 1200, 9600, etc. bits per second. This setting needs to be agreed on by sender and receiver for things to work. And data start bit would be used to synchronize the sender and receiver, i.e., the timer is set to the bit rate and upon the start bit, it starts running. Since logic low and logic high both have levels different from GND, you can synchronize on 0 bits as you can on 1 bits. This is why you may not need start or stop bits much less parity bits, all of which are options that can be set, and need to be agreed on for things to work.

EDIT: I am adding another observation: TTL usually has a threshold for high way below the nominal 5V, for example 2V, while low is GND. So a 3.3V "low voltage" level would trigger a classical 5V TTL circuit as high. For RS232 the level is 3V. So anything from 3V to 13V is considered high. However, what is really different about RS232 is that low is not GND but negative, -3V to -13V. This allows both 0 and 1 values to be detected as different from nothing, which certainly helps in "asynchronous" operation without a shared clock line.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you said (Im just a 1stYear Comp Sci Student) but this is the exact question that was given to me: You will be using an oscilloscope to investigate serial port of the Raspberry Pi. One
standard for serial communications is RS-232, but the port we will use is 3.3V TTL. 
                     12. Draw the waveform you would expect for one byte sent over this serial link.

Comment: @ManBear I just updated my text a little. But I suggest you do some Internet searching around also. There are many intro articles. The more you read around the more exposure you'll get so that you learn more.